# How do Android TV box software developers ensure best compatibility from third party apps for their (gyroscopic) remote controls?

Tags: android, keyboard

To explain my question, a bit of info about my test setup might help. I have a Moto Z, with a Moto Mod projector (my spoilt son's christmas present). I've now added a gyroscopic probox2 remote/gamepad, so he can theoretically use his phone while projecting, for films/games, without tapping the phone (which is behind him).

I've connected it and it works to an extent. It works in the core Android UI (home screen, app launcher, settings etc). However it doesn't work at all in most APPs. It works in Amazon Prime, for example, but not in Netflix.

I was expecting it to work pretty much seamlessly, as it would on Android TV boxes, even though I'm connecting it to a phone.

I've noticed it seems to identify itself to Android as a keyboard, rather than a gamepad, which makes sense since the gyroscopic "air mouse" functionality wouldn't necessarily make sense on a gamepad. The gboard popup disappears when the remote is connected, even though the remote itself doesn't have an actual keyboard. The remote allows you to switch between a sort of gamepad mode and a mouse mode, although in both cases identified as a keyboard.

Because it doesn't work out of the box in Android, and I think somebody would have noticed on an Android TV if it didn't work with Netflix, then I'm assuming Android TV developers do something to force compatibility from APPs that aren't allowing input from a "keyboard".

Possibly a service that detects "keyboard" presses and simultaneously triggers a "gamepad" press?

That's how I would probably approach it, and I assume that's how the non-root "button remapper" type APPs approach it, because they can't interfere with the actual button mapping file... but it might not be the best/easiest way?

Any ideas?

Comment: I think people are voting my question down here without reading it properly. My question is perfectly valid, I've done a lot of searching and found nothing. To an Android TV developer the problem must be a common one and easily answered, there is nothing unusual in the setup apart from the scenario of a phone being used like a TV box. Which can't be very common.

Comment: Are you developing actually software for Android TV? If yes, please show your code, what you did so far and where erorrs occur. If you just want make some hacky DIY project, you may consult other Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: The issue is that this is a very broad question. No programming question, just a broadstroke survey  soliciting ideas of how people solve this. And this isn't how StackOverflow works. It has nothing to do with people not reading your question properly. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) as suggested when you signed up today (with more specifics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)), to get a better idea of on- and off-topic questions.

Comment: I don't see that it is broad. Would it be better to re-phrase it as "How do Android TV installations trigger gamepad presses from keyboard presses?". But that seems to be a leading question if that isn't how they actually solve it. It must be a commonplace Android TV issue.

Answer (score 0):

Having looked into this further I think I understand.

APPs for Android TV are maintained separately from their mobile counterparts (https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/netflix-inc/netflix-android-tv/netflix-android-tv-3-3-2-build-1530-release/netflix-android-tv-3-3-2-build-1530-android-apk-download/) and it's not possible to side-load them without getting hacky.

So that's basically the answer - the approach in the Android TV industry to ensure compatibility with keyboards, mice, and media remotes etc, is to create separate versions of apps for Android TV which support them. On mobile, presumably developers are mainly interested in ensure physical keyboards work in text input areas, rather than in all areas in unusual cases like mine.

Which doesn't help me at all.

The not so good ways of doing it... There's possibly an approach of creating a virtual gamepad, mapped to the key presses of the physical keyboard (i.e. remote). An example of an app which appears to do just this, requires root in order to do so https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.locnet.gamekeyboard2&hl=en_GB